# A question about the measurability of convex sets.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convex-geometry

Let $E$ be a convex set of $\mathbb{R}^N$, symmetric respect to the origin and bounded. Is it true that there exists an $L^1$ function $l(\theta)$ defined on $S^{N-1}$ with values in $\mathbb{R}^{+}$ such that
$$ E=\{ t \cdot \theta : \, 0 \leq t \leq l(\theta) ,\, \theta \in S^{N-1} \}.$$
And what if I consider unbounded sets instead?
This fact was crucial for me to prove the following lemma.

Prove that an isoperimetric set $E$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is symmetrical with respect to origin and convex is necessarily a ball.
The whole proof stands on proving that the function $l(\theta)$ that I introduced is constant. But I need to prove that $l(\theta)$ admits Lebesgue points first, so I need $l(\theta)$ to be in $L^1(S^{N-1})$ for the Lebesgue differentiation theorem to work, right?

Comment: The multiplication $\mathbb{R}^+ \times S^{N-1} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^N: (t,\theta) \mapsto t \cdot \theta$ is measurable. Also $E$ is convex, hence measurable. Then $l(\theta) = \sup \{ t \in \mathbb{R}^+ | t \cdot \theta \in E\}$ is measurable. Since $E$ is bounded, also $l$ is bounded, hence integrable.

Comment: @abcdef Is the set $ \{ t \in \mathbb{R} : t\cdot \theta \in E \}$ measurable because it coincides with $m_{\theta}^{-1}(E),$ where $m_{\theta}$ is the application $t \to \theta \cdot t$? Anyway thanks for the help!